# How do I use SQL injection prevention methods when processing the form?

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

### Form

```
<FORM method="post" action="for.php">
        <input type="text" name="first" placeholder="first"><br>
        <input type="text" name="last" placeholder="last">
        <input type="submit">
    </FORM>
```

### Form Processing

How do I use SQL injection prevention methods when processing the form. I checked this link and I am confused after reading it: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

```
<?php

$db_username = "sanoj";
$db_password = "123456";
try {
 #connection 
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=localtest', $db_username, $db_password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$data = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO test (first, last) VALUES (:first, :last)');

$first = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['first']);
$last = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['last']);
$data->execute(array(':first' => $first, ':last' => $last));
#exception handiling
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

### Error

When I run the above code am getting this ERROR

> Deprecated: mysql_real_escape_string(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\Users\logon\Documents\NetBeansProjects\teste local\for.php on line 11

Comment: this is only notcie as you are using `mysql_real_escape_string()` whici is `deprecated` are you able to insert any thing into database

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 data are inserted but getting error like mentioned above

Comment: Just use this http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: check the anwer than. Hope it explain some thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `PDO` prepared statements to execute your SQL queries there is no need to manually escape the inputs for SQL Injection.

You could just pass the parameters as they are submitted:

```
$first = $_POST['first'];
$last = $_POST['last'];
$data->execute(array(':first' => $first, ':last' => $last));
```

and the extension will take care of the rest.

Note: That is only a warning and you will get it whenever you try to use `mysql_*` extension functions with new versions of PHP.

Note 2: This only protects you from `SQL Injection` attacks so keep in mind there are numerous other ways a malicious user could exploit your code using XSS and an endless number of other attacks.

** UPDATE **

The warning is nothing to be worried if you are handling that variable with caution. To get rid of it you could use:

```
$first = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'first', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)
$last = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'last', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)
```

[Warning "Do not Access Superglobal $_POST Array Directly" on Netbeans 7.4 for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767894/warning-do-not-access-superglobal-post-array-directly-on-netbeans-7-4-for-ph)

Comment: what is the best way to protect from this OR what method i can use

Comment: As i said in my answer, since you are using prepared statements you are already protected from MySQL Injection in the same way mysqli real escape string would protect you against this type of attacks.

Comment: You don't have to, that's the point. Just use the code as in my answer since you are using `PDO`.

Comment: getting warning do not access super global $_POST directly

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `mysqli_real_escape_string` here as PDO will take care of it. You can just simply pass your values in `execute()`.

Try this:

```
<?php

$db_username = "sanoj";
$db_password = "123456";

#connection
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=localtest', $db_username, $db_password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$data = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO test (first, last) VALUES (:first, :last)');

$data->execute(array(':first' => $_POST['first'], ':last' => $_POST['last']));
```

The error you are getting is to inform you that `mysql_real_escape_string` is deprecated. You can read about it here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012642/what-is-the-pdo-equivalent-of-mysql-real-escape-string

That is a bad practice and just a temp fix to get rid of the notice...

Comment: data is not inserted in table bad idea

Comment: its of no use nothing happen still negative result