# Single quote escaping in PHP + MySQL + PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, escaping

I need help with escaping a single quote. I have checked a lot of material out there, but I am not that savvy enough to make use of it. My PHP code is below.

```
<?php
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tool", 'root', 'password');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, 1);
    $rne = file_get_contents('/path/export.txt');

    $sql = "
        LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/UCBTexport.txt'INTO TABLE tool_tbl FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ( Bug_ID, Date_Tool_Ran, Headline, Submitted_By, Create_Modify_Date, Severity, Status );
        UPDATE `tool_tbl` SET `Release_Notes`= '$rne' WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID()
        ";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $i = 0;

    do {
        $i++;
    }
    while ($stmt->nextRowset())
        ;

    $error = $stmt->errorInfo();
    if ($error[0] != "00000")
    {
        echo "Query $i failed: " . $error[2];
    }
    else
    {
        echo "inserted Successfully";
    }
    die();
```

Both my queries have text that can occasionally contain all types of special characters. How do I use the mysql_real_escape_string within this code to escape special characters?

Comment: Please have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012642/what-is-the-pdo-equivalent-of-mysql-real-escape-string

Comment: Dennis. thanks for the link, i did have a look at it before posting here. I dont understand one thing though, if i do not have to escape, why i still have problems inserting text with single quotes.

Comment: I've updated your code a bit. If this was a direct copy of your existing code, please try to replace it and run it. :)

Comment: @Dennis PDO construct requires 3 arguments, in your change it reduced to 1. Please set place for closing `"` properly.

Comment: @u_mulder my edit is not approved yet, so you don't see it yet, lol :)

Comment: I see as I can, and I can even reject it, lol

Comment: I do thank you for the effort, but it did not work. I still have the same error. and It did not connect to the DB at all. so i retained the connection part as my original code and kept the other edits. But they do not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname="tool", 'root', 'password');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, 1);

    $rne = file_get_contents('/path/export.txt');
    $rne = mysql_real_escape_string($rne); >>>> this is the addition that fixed 

       $sql = "
            LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/UCBTexport.txt'INTO TABLE tool_tbl FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ( Bug_ID, Date_Tool_Ran, Headline, Subm
            itted_By, Create_Modify_Date, Severity, Status );
            UPDATE `tool_tbl` SET `Release_Notes`= '$rne' WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID()
              ";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$i = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one it may help you**

```
<?php
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tool", 'root', 'password');
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, 1);
        $rne = file_get_contents('/path/export.txt');

            $sql = <<<SQL
    LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/UCBTexport.txt' INTO TABLE tool_tbl FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ( Bug_ID, Date_Tool_Ran, Headline, Submitted_By, Create_Modify_Date, Severity, Status );
    UPDATE `tool_tbl` SET `Release_Notes`= '$rne' WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID()
    SQL;

        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $i = 0;

           do {
              $i++;
              } 
           while ($stmt->nextRowset());


         $error = $stmt->errorInfo();
          if ($error[0] != "00000")

              { 
            echo "Query $i failed: " . $error[2];
              }
            else
              {
            echo "inserted Successfully";
              }
      die();
```

Comment: Navjot, although your comment did point me in the direction to get it fixed. It was a very simple one, which is what i came here looking for. I just had to add the line $rne = mysql_real_escape_string($rne);

Answer (score 0):

Try by replacing with this.

```
$sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/UCBTexport.txt' INTO TABLE `tool_tbl` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','( Bug_ID, Date_Tool_Ran, Headline, Submitted_By, Create_Modify_Date, Severity, Status ) ;
SET @last_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
UPDATE `tool_tbl` SET `Release_Notes`= $rne WHERE id=@last_id";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a old question but I wrote this answer because the accepted answer use mysql_real_escape_string() that are deprecated.

> Can use $stmt->bindParam(":parameter_name", $php_variable, PDO::PARAM_STR); and don't need to escape
>   single quote

```
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tool", 'root', 'password');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, 1);
    $rne = file_get_contents('/path/export.txt');

       $sql = "
        LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/UCBTexport.txt'INTO TABLE tool_tbl FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ( Bug_ID, Date_Tool_Ran, Headline, Subm
itted_By, Create_Modify_Date, Severity, Status );
UPDATE `tool_tbl` SET `Release_Notes`= :rne WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID()
         ";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(":rne", $rne, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
```