# PDO MYSQL escape single quote in text

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I use this code (extract) to run an INSERT query to a MYSQL DB:

```
        try{
            $s = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO crediti SET
                nota = '$nota',
                scad_nota = '$data_nota',
                chiusa = '$nota_chiusa'
            ");
            $s->execute();
        }
        catch (PDOException $e){
            $error .= 'Errore nel caricare il credito: '.$e->getMessage();
            $table .= '<td class="report err" colspan="2">'.$error.'</td>';
            //aggiungo una riga in errore al conteggio
            $g = $g + 1;
            continue;
        }
```

$nota takes some text that can contains single quote like for example:

> ceduto a Valentini nell'ottobre 2010

that as you can see contains a single quote between nell and ottobre (sorry for italian but the meaning is not in scope actually).
How should I handle $nota to be able to insert it in the db? With my actual code it breaks for the reason of that single quote:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'ottobre..

I have read a lot on SO and googling around. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012642/what-is-the-pdo-equivalent-of-mysql-real-escape-string) question and as far as I understand my code shouldn't have any problem. Any help?

Comment: Use bound parameters. That will fix this, as well as helping you write more secure code.

Comment: http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements or escape your data input(s). http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/ - sarà molto bene ;-) *arriverderLa*

Comment: @andrewsi if you say bindParams yes, I can go for that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- you are right (also with your italian :) ). This specific query comes from a data load of financial data from excel into a mysql table for a intranet webapp. So I am confortable about sql injection this time. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @LelioFaieta prego Lelio! *buongiorno/buona sera*

Comment: *"(sorry for italian but the meaning is not in scope actually)"* - No problema, Ho capito bene ;-)