# Escape raw SQL queries in Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, laravel, laravel-4

How does one go about escaping parameters passed to a raw query in Laravel 4? I expected something like `DB::escape()` (which rings a bell from Laravel 3) and also attempted `DB::quote()` (which I thought could be available through the [PDO object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php))

```
$query = DB::select("SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.id = " . DB::escape($userId));
```

**We can't use the select method with placeholders as the above is just a simplified example of what we are trying to achieve.** We have a large custom query with a few nested select queries that cannot be adapted to the query builder.

What is the best approach to escaping something prior to inserting in Laravel 4?

EDIT:

I've just discovered that you can access the PDO object and use the quote function on it this way. Is this still the best approach, or is there an easier way to access this function?

```
DB::connection()->getPdo()->quote("string to quote");
```

Comment: Thanks. +1 for including the solution (you could also have posted it separatedly as an answer, and accepted it... could save some time for us)

Comment: @J.Bruni, good point! I've now added it as an actual answer as well so it should be easier to find.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can quote your strings this way, through the `DB` facade.

```
DB::connection()->getPdo()->quote("string to quote");
```

I did put this answer in my question when I discovered it, however I've now put it in as an actual answer to make it easier for others to find.

Comment: Thanks! It's amazing how people are adamant about answering the wrong question. I need the same answer as you did, and parameters do not work in my situation either.

Comment: Works, but such a long thing to call! DB::escape() would be nice.

Comment: @Andrew Sums up frameworks functionality

Answer (score 23):

```
$value = Input::get("userID");

$results = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.id = :value"), array(
   'value' => $value,
 ));
```

More Details [HERE](http://fideloper.com/laravel-raw-queries)

Comment: This does not answer the question, it stated that I was not looking for the solution with placeholders but rather the appropriate way to escape one variable.

Comment: @Dwight: As is moot. As you escape to actually encode the variable value as SQL, so does the placeholder. So does PDO.

Comment: beware, I have had problems using this combined with more `where` statements. The query builder does not combine the placeholders in the `select()` and the other dynamic replacements like in the `where`.

Comment: @hakre What if I need to escape a bunch (a variable number) of variables to put into an "IN ()" part of a statement?

Comment: @Janis: You find such questions answered in [Can I bind an array to an IN() condition?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/920353/367456) and it's sister Q&A.

Answer (score 11):

You may also try this, ([Read Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/database#running-queries))

```
$results = DB::select('SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.id = ?', array($userId));
```

Comment: +1 to this answer. Using array bindings, like the example above, will protect you. Further info here http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=11068

Comment: This does not answer the question, it stated that I was not looking for the solution with placeholders but rather the appropriate way to escape one variable.

Comment: @Dwight, This is what the `array binding/bound params` does, safe, escaped, no sql injections could be applied and not only place holders. Just read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716373/real-escape-string-and-pdo) to clear yourself.

Comment: @Dwight, also notice the first comment, didn't it clarify you ?

Answer (score 9):

Two answers here, that I use, have less verbose solutions built into the `DB` facade.

First, [value quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23208367/244826):

```php
// From linked answer
DB::connection()->getPdo()->quote("string to quote");
// In the DB facade
DB::getPdo()->quote('string to quote');
```

Second, [identifier quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31654605/244826) (table and column names):

```php
// From linked answer
DB::table('x')->getGrammar()->wrap('table.column');
// In the DB facade
DB::getQueryGrammar()->wrap('table.column');
```

Answer (score 5):

I found this question when looking for generic sql escaping in Laravel. What I actually needed though was table/column name escaping. So, for future reference:

```
/**
 * Quotes database identifier, e.g. table name or column name. 
 * For instance:
 * tablename -> `tablename`
 * @param  string $field 
 * @return string      
 */
function db_quote_identifier($field) {
  static $grammar = false;
  if (!$grammar) {
    $grammar = DB::table('x')->getGrammar(); // The table name doesn't matter.
  }
  return $grammar->wrap($field);
}
```

Comment: `DB::query()->getGrammar()` might be a more straightforward approach. Keeps other devs from asking too many questions.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using this in my `helpers.php` at Laravel 5:

```
if ( ! function_exists('esc_sql'))
{
    function esc_sql($string)
    {
        return app('db')->getPdo()->quote($string);
    }
}
```

Then I can use `esc_sql` function where I need to pergorm escaping for raw SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fuller example, showing how to escape both values and columns and extend Laravel's querybuilder:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;


class DatabaseQueryBuilderMacroProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register() {
        Builder::macro('whereInSet', function($columnName, $value) {
            /** @var \Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar $grammar */
            $grammar = $this->getGrammar();
            return $this->whereRaw('FIND_IN_SET(?,' . $grammar->wrap($columnName) . ')', [$value]);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[PHP Heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

$sql = <<<SQL
  WITH table1 AS(SELECT...
SQL;

$parameters = [1,2,3,...]

$table = DB::select($sql, $parameters);
```