# How to escape a query using an Eloquent model select?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

`DB::select` takes a second parameter as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18951103/65387), but `Eloquent::select` does not.

Here's my query:

```
Feature::where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)
            ->select('id','name',DB::raw("exists(select * from vehicle_features vf where vf.vehicle_id=$id and vf.feature_id=feature.id) as `checked`"))
            ->orderBy('name')->get(),
```

How can I ensure `$id` is escaped properly?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`DB::getPdo()->quote($id)`](http://www.neontsunami.com/post/escaping-variables-in-raw-sql-queries-in-laravel-4).

```
->select(
    'id',
    'name',
    DB::raw(
        "exists(select * from vehicle_features vf where vf.vehicle_id="
        . DB::getPdo()->quote($id)
        . " and vf.feature_id=feature.id) as `checked`"
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use PDO or easier manually add binding to the Query:

```
Feature::select(
     'id',
     'name',
     // replace $id here
     DB::raw("exists(select * from vehicle_features vf where vf.vehicle_id=? and vf.feature_id=feature.id) as `checked`"))
     // and add this part
  ->addBinding($id)
  ->where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)
  ->orderBy('name')->get();
```

---

edit: as stated in the comments below, bindings are bugged and methods order does matter, so the above will work as expected.

Comment: That conflicts with the bindings used in the `where` clause; it's getting the order mixed up.

Comment: No, it does not mix the order unless you changed the order of that chain.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, I'm looking at the query it generated my laravel-debugbar, and I can clearly see that the two parameter replacements are backwards. And that makes sense because the `where` clause actually comes after the `select` clause, even though I've added it first.

Comment: Mark, query bindings are added to the query in the same order as the chained methods, so it doesn't matter if it's WHERE that will go to the end or anything else. You may use Model::where(..)->select(..DB::raw())->addBinding()->where(..) ... and the order will be exactly the same.

Comment: I'm not convinced. My understanding is that Laravel builds a full SQL query and then runs it through PDO at the end. The parameters get pushed into an array as they're added; if the SQL comes out in a different order, then they won't align. But there's no sense arguing about it, I've written a test: [this code](http://pastebin.com/7t0SSU69) produces [this result](http://i.imgur.com/lQtjLpZ.png)

Comment: We can take it one step further: http://pastebin.com/8reK1hTJ When you add the binding matters!

Comment: Uhm, yes you are 100% right. Sorry for that mistake. I just checked other possibilities of chaining and apparently it's bugged. I'm going to give it a closer look and find a fix for that.