# Order nulls last using laravel

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel

I am trying to sort a query (to a postgresql database) in laravel so that nulls are last.

The code for the order by is

```
$dbObj->orderBy($aSearchFilters["sidx"],$aSearchFilters["sord"]);
```

I found [How to sort NULL values last using Eloquent in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644072/how-to-sort-null-values-last-using-eloquent-in-laravel) but all of these have a fixed column that is being sorted on. Is their a way of getting NULLS LAST added to the order by without introducing sql injection issues?

Comment: Should escaping the input values before passing them to `DB::raw()` solve your concern? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326695/how-to-escape-a-query-using-an-eloquent-model-select

Comment: No. Postgres does not like it when you have something like ORDER BY 'colName'

Comment: Use `orderByRaw`. Its second parameter is bindings, so it is injection-protected.

Comment: Please Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644072/how-to-sort-null-values-last-using-eloquent-in-laravel) accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

`orderByRaw` is an injection-protected method. In the following example I order by a nullable field. The biggest `field` comes first, `NULLs` comes after the smallest `field`.

```
Posts::where('type', 'fix')
    ->orderByRaw('field DESC NULLS LAST')
```

Comment: @Tamim what do you see in `...->toSql()`?