# Is 'my_real_escape_string' required after I validated and sanitized form data?

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

So I have validated and sanitized my form data on the same document. I was thinking it was safe until I started seeing stuff about the `'my_real_escape_string'`.

I am thinking that my data will be secure if I enter it how I have it but am not wanting to take the chance. So my question is do I need to use this `'my_real_escape_string'` to ensure data security.

I am using the code below. First will be the form document (index.php) itself and then processing document`(processform.php)`. Thanks for any and all help.

**//index.php**

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$first_nameErr = $last_nameErr = $emailErr = $passwordErr = $genderErr = "";
$first_name = $last_name = $email = $password = $gender = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
if (empty($_POST["first_name"]))
 {$first_nameErr = "";}
else
 {
 $first_name = test_input($_POST["first_name"]);
 // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
 if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$first_name))
   {
   $first_nameErr = "Only letters allowed";
   }
  }

if (empty($_POST["last_name"]))
 {$last_nameErr = "";}
else
 {
 $last_name = test_input($_POST["last_name"]);
 // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$last_name))
   {
   $last_nameErr = "Only letters allowed";
   }
 }


if (empty($_POST["email"]))
  {$emailErr = "";}
else
 {
 $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
 // check if e-mail address syntax is valid
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email))
   {
   $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
   }
  }


if (empty($_POST["password"]))
 {$passwordErr = "";}
else
 {$password = test_input($_POST["password"]);}

if (empty($_POST["gender"]))
 {$genderErr = "";}
else
 {$gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);}

}

function test_input($data)
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}
?>



<div class="signupitsfree" float="right">
<p class="signup">Sign Up<br />It's Completely Free!</p>


<form method="POST" name="signup" action="processform.php">

<label for="first name"></label><input id="first name" name="first_name" 
placeholder="First Name" type="text" value="<?php echo $first_name;?>" /> <span  
class="error">* <?php echo $first_nameErr;?></span>

<label for="last_name"></label><input id="last name" name="last_name"  
placeholder="Last 
Name" type="text" value="<?php echo $last_name;?>" />
<span class="error">* <?php echo $last_nameErr;?></span>
<br><br>


<label for="email"></label><input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"    
type="text" value="<?php echo $email;?>" />
<span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
<br /><br />


<label for="password"></label><input id="password" name="password" 
placeholder="Create  
Password" type="password" />
<span class="error">* <?php echo $passwordErr;?></span>
<br /><br />
<label for="male"><strong>Male</strong></label> <input id="male" value="male" 
<?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male") echo "checked";?> 
name="gender" type="radio" /> 
<label for="female"><strong>Female</strong></label> <input id="female" value="female" 
<?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female") echo "checked";?> name="gender"  
type="radio" />
<span class="error">* <?php echo $genderErr;?></span>
<br /><br />
<label for="submit">"I Agree To <a href="#">Terms And Conditions"</a></label>
```

//BELOW IS 'PROCESSFORM.PHP'

```
<?php

 $hostname="this is correct";
 $username="thisalso";
 $password="chicken";
 $dbname="chiken also";

  $db_conx = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE ("Unable to
  connect to database! Please try again later.");

  if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
  echo mysqli_connect_error();
  exit();
  }

  $select = mysqli_select_db($db_conx,$dbname);

  $first_name= $_POST["first_name"];
  $last_name= $_POST["last_name"];
  $email= $_POST["email"];
  $password= $_POST["password"];
  $gender= $_POST["gender"];

  mysqli_query($db_conx,"INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email, password,   gender)
  VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', '$password', '$gender')");
  mysqli_close($db_conx);

  header("Location: anotherpage.php")
  ?>
```

Comment: `mysql_*_escape_string` **does not "sanitize" data** (that is, it it *outside* the scope of business rules!): it is a hack to prevent SQL Injection. Always apply *business rules* to the data and use *placeholders* to prevent SQL Injection. They are two *different* issues. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: with mysqli you should use prepared statements

Comment: @ user2864740   OK I think I understand now. So as a web designer do you have to use hacks to prevent hacks?

Comment: @user3066599 No. Placeholders are not a hack. Business rules (and validation therein) are not a hack. Placeholders prevent *SQL Injection* (or, changing the *shape* of the query) while business rules ensure that only "valid" data is allowed. (The database schema should be appropriately typed to provide fail-safe rules/limits where applicable.)

Comment: This can support Maz lqbal answered

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716373/real-escape-string-and-pdo

Comment: Actually, `mysql_real_escape_string()` is _not_ a hack. It's a legitimate tool to escape your data safely in a locale-aware way. Prepared statements are not always the best approach, and sometimes they're not easily usable, so a proper tool to escape data is essential.

Comment: I see. So will the placeholders encrypt the password?

Comment: @MikeW Anyone who asks so generally about `mysql_*_escape_string` is not ready for `mysql_*_escape_string`: there are *some* cases for it, but they are not the norm and should be *very carefully* considered.

Comment: @user3066599 Not at all! Placeholders prevent [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (and *nothing* more): "SQL injection is a code injection technique, used to attack data driven applications, in which malicious SQL statements are inserted into an entry field for execution (e.g. to dump the database contents to the attacker)."

Comment: Oh I see. Well The business rules and the placeholders will allow me to stop sql injections. Thanks for the information.

Comment: So what is used to encrypt the passwords before I let you go

Comment: Because I can see in my table that the password is as I put it in

Comment: @user3066599 Business rules aren't related to SQL Injection (directly): rather, they ensure that the *information* is "valid". For instance, that a person can only "die" *after* they are "born" (some rules can/should be encoded in the databases while other can/should be in the application or DAL, depending upon how one views the business rules and application of such).

Comment: @user3066599 Oh no! Do not encrypt passwords, that's an entirely different situation not related to `mysql_*_escape_string`. Passwords should be hashed (with bcrypt or scrypt - not SHA!) with an appropriate salt.

Comment: Ok I will look into that. Thanks for your help. I now have a better understanding.

Comment: I have my answers and am appreciative of all answers.

Comment: If you have any additional information on this matter it will be accepted with open arms but I think I am on the right path to researching and finding out.

Comment: A special thanks to  user2864740

Comment: Just like users before me said, you should use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 4):

The catch frase we always hear about `mysql*_real_escape_string()` is *to avoid SQL injection* , so it's perfectly clear that some people develop their own twisted and complicated system to *sanitize* any input and think: "Ok, now my input is "safe", I'm not needing to avoid SQL injection anymore".

But that's wrong, simply because `mysql*_real_escape_string()`, and prepared statements, are **not** to avoid SQL injection. They're in place to **avoid breaking the query** (I know, they're also for SQL injection, but because *SLQ injection work by breaking your query and hijacking it*, adding parts, removing others, etc)

Look at your code:

```
  $first_name= $_POST["first_name"];
  $last_name= $_POST["last_name"];
  $email= $_POST["email"];
  $password= $_POST["password"];
  $gender= $_POST["gender"];

  mysqli_query($db_conx,"INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email, password,   gender)
  VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', '$password', '$gender')");
```

Now, I'm a genuine and naive user, I don't even know what an injection is, so I'm not a user you should not trust. I register to your site, I put my data there: name `Ian`, lastname `O'Really`.

What? Database error? Why?

That's it. If I put a quote in your query, it breaks, because the quote *ends* the string where it shouldn't, and your db receives

```
INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email, password,   gender)
  VALUES ('Ian', 'O'Really'
```

which is an SQL syntax error.

That's why we need **escaping** functions, not because of ninja hackers always lurking to destroy our user table and pawn our server, but because we don't want the query to be broken as soon as a syntax characters is put in the wrong position, unescaped.

***Validation* has nothing to do with *escaping***

You ***validate*** when you want your data to be in a **valid** format: a date must be formatted as date, a username cannot contain spaces, a password must be minum 8 chars, etc. Those are *valid* inputs for ***your*** program (in my app I might want totally different rules), and for this reason you validate them.

***Escaping*** on the other hand is to allow control characters to be inserted without their original meaning, making them a regular character without special meaning: you escape `<` so that it won't be an html start of tag and be a potential XSS issue, you escape the quotes to avoid breaking a query, and so on.

Different things for different situation, please keep that in mind.

Comment: I can't believe I see such a sane answer under PHP tag.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you do need the escape string, because your information you'r sending will be visible for the user. So for instance. You have a shopping cart system. They can just add items in from the URL. So if you want to have it secure, use the escape string.

Cheers,
Jesse

Comment: Wha-‽ What does "visibility" and "from the URL" have to do with this?