# PDO query returns "Array" instead of value

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to get a list of usernames from my following table, and then use that list to get each user's post for a news feed, but when I try this:

```
    $sth = $db->query("SELECT profile FROM follows WHERE follower='$username' ");
    $following = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach ($following as $userlist) {
        $userlist_logic .= "username='$userlist' OR ";
    }

echo $userlist_logic;
```

Then it just returns this:

> username='Array' OR username='Array' OR username='Array' OR

How do I fix it?

Comment: There will be a trailing `OR` at the end of your query with this logic

Comment: I suspect he'll trim it off with `preg_replace('/ OR $/', '', $userlist_logic);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$userlist` is an array instance containing the `profile` column for each row returned.

The line within your foreach loop needs to be as follows:

```
$userlist_logic .= "username='{$userlist['profile']}' OR ";
```

Also, I would recommend sanitising the variable before interpolating it into the string by generating your second SQL statement within PDO and then running it through PDO prepare as detailed in [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716373/real-escape-string-and-pdo).

Answer (score 0):

In the loop do:

```
foreach ($following as $userlist) {
   $userlist_logic[] = "username='{$userlist['profile']}'";
}
```

Then just implode the array you created to create a list of that joined with `OR`:

```
$userlist_logic = implode(' OR ', $userlist_logic);
```