# PHP SQL query how to have ' in variables

Tags: mysql

This is properly going to be a really simple question but my head is spinning.

I am using php in a web service. One item that i receive is a string which i save into an sql database.

Issue is the strings must be able to contain   '   but when i construct a query like the following

```
$query = "INSERT INTO TABLE (COLUMN1) VALUES ('{$_POST('string')}')";
```

it throws sql query error if ' is used.

Any solutions

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to properly escape your strings that you insert into your database.

MySQLi resource: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

PDO resource: [real escape string and PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716373/real-escape-string-and-pdo)

Answer (score 0):

I think the word you are looking fore is **escape**.

have a look at this:  [How does one escape special characters when writing SQL queries?](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/how_does_one_escape_special_characters_when_writing_sql_queries)

Answer (score 0):

Its always better to use a prepared statements for queries that involve user input.
Your SQL string must be something like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table (column1) VALUES(?)";
```

See [mysqli_prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) documentation if you are using mysqli.
If you are using a PHP framework, your framework may offer an easier implementation.

Checkout [this article](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/sql-injection-prevention/) for the reasons why its better to use a prepared statement.