# Making a safe query, mysqli_real_escape_string alternative

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question about how to make a string safe to run in a query, generally.

I have a `secure_input` function, which drags all the `$_POST` and `$_GET` through a few PHP functions to make it safe, and it seems that re-formatting works, but I still get an error with singlequotes, even though they are properly escaped with backslash from `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.

Here's how it runs:

```
// function which drives on every post and get
function secureinput($link, $value) {
    $value = htmlentities(stripslashes($value));
    $value = str_ireplace("script", "blocked", $value);
    $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $value);
    return $value;
}

// then I got another function which performs all of the mysqli requests and it starts with converting all the post and get data
if(isset($_POST)) {
    foreach($_POST as $post) {
        $post = secureinput($link, $post);
        echo "post converted<pre>" . $post . "</pre><br />";
    }
}
if(isset($_GET)) {
    foreach($_GET as $get) {
        $get = secureinput($link, $get);
        echo "get converted<pre>" . $get . "</pre><br />";
    }
}
```

The output looks pretty fit for query, but the query is still broken:

> "Some text that doesn\'t work"

How can it still fail?

I have a `ckeditor` implemented for some textareas, and it sends an alternative for singlequotes, which works perfectly in a query, `ckeditor` replaces them with S#39; (& instead of S).

Is there a function in PHP which can do the same, instead of backslashes? It would also be pretty good to have singlequotes formatted in the same way.

Comment: What about prepared statements using a modern api?

Answer (score 0):

If you use PDO you have built in functions that do this for you. Check [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716373/real-escape-string-and-pdo)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid such undesired behavior such as possible SQL injections, I would suggest you using prepared statements provided by mysqli extension as describe [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Another option is using [PDO abstraction layer](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).