# Mysqli prepared statement for non dynamic variable

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm learning mysqli prepared statements and have a few questions about it

1. From what I have understood we use prepared statement for those queries that have dynamic variable in them for eg in login - email & password.

   I want to know if prepared statements are necessary for queries where no dynamic element is there for eg fetching users from database. If I do this  like below query does this makes it vulnerable

   ```
   SELECT 
       name, email 
   FROM
       users
   ```
2. How can I use prepared statement without using bind param?

Like in pdo we do like this

```
$array=array($email,$pass);
$db->query("SELECT name from users where email=? and password=?");
$db->execute($array);
```

Can I do something like this in mysqli? I have searched and found results that use bind param , nothing without using bind.?

Comment: First one is quite silly and you can answer it yourself. As for the second - either write a *wrapper* of your own or switch to PDO.

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108414/mysqli-query-vs-prepare

Answer (score -1):

Your answers are as follows:

1.See this-[stackoverflow.com/questions/5108414/mysqli-query-vs-prepare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108414/mysqli-query-vs-prepare)-(the link that AdRock posted in his comment.)

2.Instead of-

```
$db->query("SELECT name from users where email=? and password=?");
$db->bind_param("ss", $email, $password);
$db->execute($array);
```

You can do this-

```
$db->query("SELECT name from users where email='$email' and password='$password'");
$db->execute($array);
```

Comment: Oh no. This answer is worse than no answer at all