# Is using Laravel effectively with AWS RDS Proxy possible?

Tags: php, laravel, database, proxy

We have a Laravel-application that is running in AWS.
For the database we have an AuroraMySQL instance.
Not so recently we added a RDS-proxy in an attempt to optimize things.

## Is the Proxy an improvement though?

While technically we have no issues and everything is working, we later realized that instead of the proxy pooling the database connection and potentially needing less connections to the database, the proxy ended up creating a connection for each request anyway, **which would mean we do not gain anything really** by the proxy then.
We noticed that, because i opened the application in 20 different browser tabs which resulted in a 'max-connection alert'.

## After a bit of digging

turns out the problem might be Laravel itself.
As by default [all queries use 'prepare' statements by default](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/database#running-an-unprepared-statement).
Which means the connection in the proxy gets pinned to that process for that time.

Because it prepares the query first

```
Prepare select * from `users` where `id` = ?
```

And then calls it with the variable binding

```
Execute select * from `users` where `id` = 42424242
```

Of course it needs to keep the connection open if that happens in two separate calls.

## Now, there is a way...

Laravel has the the `DB::unprepared` statement, which i would assume would allow to call the above in one call and not pinning the connection,
**but I don't think we can apply that everywhere**.
Think packages and we are using Laravel-nova.
Not to mention, that we could not use the whole eloquent builder abstraction.

Another way that we have read about, could be to add the `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` option to the PDO-construction.

The question is, is that worth the effort, or do we end up running into more problems down the road?

## Related

While i have found questions regarding [the differences of prepared and unprepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521169/php-prepared-vs-not-prepared-query),
i could not yet find an answer if this generally makes sense inside a Laravel-application.

[This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63282105/does-rds-proxy-affects-current-application-side-pooling) also suggest it should still be beneficial in general (i think Laravel is reusing connections by default), but does not answer if it is feasible in Laravel specifically.

Comment: I think that `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` sounds like something you could try. It should be transparent to any queries you do with PDO.