# Laravel return int on Windows and return string on Linux

Tags: laravel

I have MySql Cloud Hosting,

> Table(Member) - Field(id, name, balance)

when I access with Laravel on Windows machine, they are(id, balance) returned as Int,

but

when I access with Laravel on Linux machine, all field returned as String.

So this issue can make calculation operation error because they read as String.
Any way to fix this issues without $casts?

Comment: Please update your post with more info and some important code. I'm sure a problem is not in Windows/Linux.

Comment: L5+MySql+Win = return Int, L5+MySql+Linux = return String, for.ex. Member::all(); or DB::table('members')->get();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP + PDO + MySQL: how do I return integer and numeric columns from MySQL as integers and numerics in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079320/php-pdo-mysql-how-do-i-return-integer-and-numeric-columns-from-mysql-as-int)

Answer (score 0):

It seems a problem is in MySQL drivers. Laravel uses prepared statements by default. You have two ways: tune your Linux setup or use conversion in your code (casts or (int)).

Please look [ticked answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412037/disabling-pdoattr-emulate-prepares-causing-unknown-issue). You need to tune `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES`

Comment: I'm not using browser, I use Postman, If U using linux all collection return as String, right? I want return as Integer

Comment: Look, you're saying that you're trying `Member::all()`. This returns a collection of all members, not integer or a string. You didn't give another examples.

Comment: Try to `echo gettype($yourCollection->user_id);` both in Linux and Windows.

Comment: on linux string, on windows integer

Comment: Ok. Are you running Laravel on Linux server and Windows server? Or server is the same and you're trying to access it from Linux/Winodws home PC?

Comment: Yes I have 1 server Linux and 1 server windows

Answer (score 0):

By the sounds of it, this is something to with MySQL and the drivers you're using as the other answer states.

That aside, this is a non-issue, PHP is a dynamically typed language so returning a string makes no difference unless you're running the value through `is_int()` which will explicitly check that it is indeed an integer. If you are doing that, don't, use `is_number()` instead as that handles all types.